# Combinations where number chosen can change?

Tags: probability

I'm currently working on a URL shortener and I'm just trying to figure out how many combinations of upper case, lower case, and numbers I can have for a given number chosen. The number chosen will change with time, it will start out with 2 characters, once that is close to be exhausted it will roll over to 3 characters, then 4, and so on.

I know that the way to calculate this is something like (n + r - 1)! / r!(n - 1) however if I am correct that's taken into account that r is a set length.

So for my purposes can I simply calculate n^r and come up with the possible combinations?

n = how many things to choose from, in my case that is 62
r = number chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string of length $r$, with each character chosen from $n$ choices, then there are exactly $n^r$ such strings.  If you have a string of length $\le r$, with each character chosen from $n$ choices, then there are exactly $$n^1+n^2+n^3+\cdots+n^r=\frac{n^{r+1}-n}{n-1}$$ such strings.